# What does SSRS technically do when it expires the cache?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2014

Our data is loaded daily.  My report can be run, using a parameter, for any number of sites (100 is the total number of sites) and I want it to cache a temporary copy of the report and expire it on a schedule - a schedule that is triggered at the end of our daily load.  This is simple.

Where it gets complicated is I have a cache refresh plan to pre-load the cache for all 100 sites.  I need to make sure the cache expires before this plan runs - a plan that is tied to a schedule I want to trigger at the end of our load.

If I trigger the jobs, in order, at the end of the load, they are effectively triggered together, so I would like to understand what happens on the system level when SSRS expires a cache so that I can ensure the refresh occurs after the expiration.  Is there a value in one of the ReportServer tables that is changed or a row deleted?

For what it's worth, this is what I am seeing in my testing (the cache is successfully pre-loaded), but I would like to understand the technical architecture to give myself a better comfort level before using this in production.

Comment: Only way I understand you can manually delete reports from the cache is through the SOAP API for SSRS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx#Anchor_1

Answer (score 0):

I see that it's an old thread but you can essentially have different Shared Schedules to expire and refresh the cache executed in that order to solve the problem.